# GET request with XHR object, URI component name not found

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to create a text box which upon having a character entered in it, queries the server.

I'm getting the following error and I don't understand why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'lift_string'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/workoutcal/views.py", line 71, in get_lifts
    search_str = request.GET['lift_string']
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'lift_string'"
```

I'm getting it when I enter a character inside of this text box:

```
 <input id="lift" name="lift_string" type="text" onkeyup="getLifts()">
```

This is the associated javascript of the text box:

```
function addURLParam(url, name, value){
    url += (url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&");
    url += encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    return url;
}

function getLifts(){

    var xhr = createXHR();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304){
                document.getElementById("xhrPar").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("xhrPar").innerHTML = "Request was unsuccessful: "+xhr.status;
            }
        }
    };

    var url = "http://localhost:8000/workoutcal/get_lifts";
    addURLParam(url, document.getElementById("lift").name, document.getElementById("lift").value);

    xhr.open("get", url, false);
    xhr.send(null);

}
```

And here is the Django view that will handle the get-request from the XHR object:

```
def get_lifts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search_str = request.GET['lift_string']
        return HttpResponse('Received lift_string')
```

It seems to me like the `lift_string` URI component name that I've added to `url` in the javascript can not be found? Why?

EDIT: Content of `request.GET`:

Adding print statement to view:

```
def get_lifts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("CONTENT OF request.GET: "+str(request.GET))
        search_str = request.GET['lift_string']
        return HttpResponse('Received lift_string')
```

Leads to this output:

```
CONTENT OF request.GET: <QueryDict: {}>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is only the Ajax request that is hitting this view? Also try printing the contents of `request.GET`.

Comment: 1. This is as far as I can tell the only Ajax request in my whole web app. There is no other occurence of an XHR object anywhere else in my whole project.
2. Added contents of request.GET in the edit. It's empty

Comment: (I meant, could it have been a non-Ajax request that is hitting that view. But never mind, Ivan has pointed out the correct answer.)

Comment: My bad, misread your message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result of `addURLParam` to `url`, like this:

```
url = addURLParam(url, document.getElementById("lift").name, document.getElementById("lift").value);
```